# How to get statistics of (internal) referrers for landing pages?

Tags: 7, nodes

I'm building a Drupal 7 site. Here's a use case that I'm not sure how to deal with:

- for a campaign, we have a specific landing page.
- we promote the landing page through different means (newsletter, flyers, website).
- we want to track the effectiveness of each promotion.

As a sample, I have mydomain.com/mylandingpage?promoId=[n] and I want to track how many people accessed that page through promoid=1 vs promoid=2.

I do not necessarily have a form on the landing page, i.e. knowing how many users submitted a form after seeing a promotion is a different use case (and one that can be solved with a hidden form field).

How can I get statistics for what I need? The only thing I can think of is making special redirect URLs for each promo, e.g. mydomain.com/mylandingpage/promo1, but that would become messy/cumbersome very soon.

I'm aware of Google Analytics, but I'm looking for an internal solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: Google Analytics springs to mind...

Comment: Yeah... I guess I was looking for an internal solution.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question, there are basically 2 approaches possible, as further detailed below (you might want to combine them also ...).

## Option 1: Use the Rules module

You can use the [Rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules) module to trigger "some" Rules **Actions**, based on the actual value specified as your `promoid`. Use either of these modules to trigger Rules **Events** based on the 'current URL being viewed' (quotes are from their project pages):

- [Rules URL Argument](https://drupal.org/project/rules_url_argument):

  > ... provides two rules conditions based on URL arguments:
  >
  > - check if a URL argument is present
  > - compare the value of an URL argument
  >
  > It also provides an action that makes the value of an URL argument available as new variable to Rules.
- [Path Rules](https://drupal.org/project/pathrules):

  > ... implements Rules conditions for checking the URL against a given string for triggering actions.

What the actual Rules **Actions** should be, is up to your own imagination, but here are just a few possibilities (rather basic, but straight forward to implement using the Rules module):

- Perform a redirect to some URL, specific to each `promoid` (and then you just count the hits for each of these URLs).
- Send an eMail each time you have a hit, whereas the content of the eMail somehow reflects the value of your `promoid`, and/or you use a different eMail ID to send such eMail to, based on that value.
- ...

## Option 2: Use a typical module about statistics

Below is a list of modules to pick from (quotes are from their project pages).

- [Statistics Advanced](https://www.drupal.org/project/statistics_advanced):

  > Provides a few advanced options to the core Statistics module.
- [Visitors](https://www.drupal.org/project/visitors):

  > Displays information about visitors, and integrates with the [WhoIs Lookup](http://drupal.org/project/whois) module
- [Better Statistics](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_statistics):

  > introduces a Statistics API, which allows for a way to collect, limit, and route custom access statistics and data.
- [Piwik Web Analytics](https://www.drupal.org/project/piwik):

  > Adds the [Piwik](http://piwik.org/) web statistics tracking system (free open source) to your website.
  >
  > Related module: [Piwik Reports](https://www.drupal.org/project/piwik_reports), which provides graphical reporting of your site's tracking data inside Drupal.
- [Chartbeat](https://www.drupal.org/project/chartbeat):

  > ... to provide third party integration with [Chartbeat](http://chartbeat.com/), for real-time site monitoring statistics.
- [Stat Counter](https://www.drupal.org/project/statcounter):

  > ... provides an integration between Drupal and StatCounter web statistics.